# For loop running to specific column

Tags: vba, excel, syntax

I am trying to change this code to only go from column 3 to a certain column farther down the workbook. Instead of what I have now, I am drawing a blank on how the syntax needs to change in order for me to be allowed to do this. Thanks!

```
For chartdatacol = 3 To Worksheets("Chart Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to loop through the last column, use

```
Worksheets("Chart Data").Cells(1, Worksheets("Chart Data").Columns.Count).end(xlToLeft).Column
```

This assumes that row 1 has data in the last column you are interested in.

So your loop would look like

```
For chartdatacol = 3 To Worksheets("Chart Data").Cells(1, Worksheets("Chart Data").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Comment: That's fine, but instead of `.Row` it should be `.Column`.

Comment: And you might as well edit the top portion to go with it.

Comment: @Ralp Done. I took out the with block because I wanted an answer that came close to what the OP had already tried. I appreciate your improvement.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, I would take the number fetching out of your for statement

```
Dim i as Integer, 
    lastCol as Integer, 
    firstCol as Integer

firstCol = 3
lastCol = mySheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

For i = firstCol to lastCol
    --Do something
Next i
```